# .predict returning binary results and not percentages

Tags: machine-learning, keras, computer-vision, classification

Hello I compiled my model as follows

`model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])`

and am just running a

`print(model.predict(test_tensor))`

which returns `[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]]`

The last layers is softmax activation so shouldn't be doing this.

EDIT: I have tried predict_proba as well and has not worked

Comment: 1.0 = 100%, that is still a percentage.

Comment: Shouldn't ever reach a 100% confidence

Comment: No, that's a typical misconception. Its common that softmax produces one-hot like probabilities.

Comment: No it's not a misconception in this case. These predictions should definitely not be 100%, I don't mean it as the status quo,  but I mean for this case the similarities between the categorizations are too high for that to occure.

Comment: I think you are completely ignoring that softmax + cross-entropy doesn't really produce meaningful confidences, the uncertainty produces by this is quite bad, as you see in your own results. In order to obtain meaningful calibrated probabilities, you have to use other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you're right, it would get infinitely closer to 1 but remember we use floating points numbers of fixed bits to represent them. Therefore, after the value reaches a certain epsilon of 1 it gets rounded. This happens for other entries as well. As such you get a prediction that is 100% confident.

Why your model predicts this? It could be that class is overrepresented, so it becomes very confident. You train for a long time so weights saturate especially if you don't have any regularisation.

Comment: All classifications are trained on about the same amount of img data (thousands each) and then uploaded. All classifications look fairly similar to each other as well so there would be no way the model could predict them 100%.